# Print to PDF in Chrome: Microsoft Print to PDF vs. Save as PDF

Tags: google-chrome, print-to-pdf

When the print dialog box opens, the **Destination** has options such as **Microsoft Print to PDF** and **Save as PDF**. What's the difference between these two options and which produces a higher-quality PDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll disagree a bit.  "Save as PDF" seems to convert the existing HTML to a PDF document and allow you to save that as a file.  The resulting PDF is text-searchable, contains embedded fonts, and the quality is better than "print to pdf."  Also, the final page dimensions will come from the HTML document styles and will not necessarily match any specific printer page size like 8.5"x11".

Now, "print to pdf" seems to take the HTML page, convert the whole thing to one image and scale it for the print driver's default page size like 8.5x11.  The resulting PDF is NOT text-searchable and the visible image quality is not as good.

I prefer "save as pdf" because the quality is better and the file is searchable.  If you need to print it later, with a real printer, it will go through a print driver and a process similar to "print to pdf" at that time - scaling to fit 8.5x11, for example.

Final note:  Different web browsers, print drivers, and software versions will produce different file sizes in the final .pdf.  There isn't one method that is necessarily always bigger/smaller than the other.